# Python build puts wrong version number in filenames

Tags: python, build, python-wheel

When I run `python -m build`, the `tar` and `whl` files that are created use the wrong version of my package in the filenames.

Here is my `setup.cfg`:

```
[metadata]
# This is required for any package to install with a name
name = stockpyl

# Since we are using a "src" layout, we need the following:
[options]
package_dir=
    =src
packages=find:

[options.packages.find]
where=src
[bumpver]
current_version = "0.0.1"
version_pattern = "MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH"
commit_message = "bump version {old_version} -> {new_version}"
commit = True
tag = True
push = False

[bumpver:file_patterns]
setup.cfg =
    current_version = "{version}"
```

The files created by `build` are named `stockpyl-0.0.0.tar.gz` and `stockpyl-0.0.0-py3-none-any.whl`. I assumed that `build` would grab the version number (0.0.1) from `setup.cfg` but it doesn't seem to be. Where does it get the version number from? How do I tell it to use the current version?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding

```
version = 0.0.1
```

under `[metadata]`.